# Web-Scraping using "requests" does not scrape the names/leaves out important information

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tried following [this](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/) approach to webscraping names of this [specific website containing names I am interested in.](https://bair.berkeley.edu/students.html):

```
import requests

URL = "https://bair.berkeley.edu/students.html"
page = requests.get(URL)

print(page.text)
```

When executing, I however only get:

1. The first  of the people listed on that website in my print output
2. When I inspect it in Chrome, it reads `<span class="name">Elaine Angelino</span>`. The printed page.text however only reads `<span class="name"></span>`.

How can I fix that issue and get all ~500 students and their names? Any help is appreciated!

I tried to find ways to extract html another way, but was not successful so far.

Comment: I would guess that the content is dynamically being generated by JavaScript. You could 1) download the html in your browser, save as a file and read from there 2) you attempt to read the network requests in the browser to see if the data is being requested as a simple JSON object 3) you could use Selenium instead of requests.

Comment: as @JohnnyJohnBoy said, the content is dynamically generated, using firebase as far as I can tell - so, there probably won't be any convenient API request you can find from the log and try to replicate. If you're willing to give Selenium a try, there's [this function](https://pastebin.com/kEC9gPC8) for selenium+bs4 scraping [for your case you'll just need to call it like `soup = linkToSoup_selenium(URL, ecx='//span[@class="name"]')` to load all the names before parsing]

Answer (score 1):

As the name list of the webpage is populated by `JavaScript`, So you can use selenium with bs4.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)

driver.get('https://bair.berkeley.edu/students.html')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
name_lst = []

for n in soup.select('.name'):
    name = n.get_text(strip=True) if n else None
    name_lst.append({'NAME':name})

df = pd.DataFrame(name_lst)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                NAME
0
1    Yasin Abbasi-Yadkori
2          Pulkit Agrawal
3         Elaine Angelino
4           Khalid Ashraf
..                    ...
624        Rein Houthooft
625            Yanyan Lan
626    Erikson Nascimento
627      Tim G. J. Rudner
628      Markus Wulfmeier

[629 rows x 1 columns]
```